# Woocommerce - if is specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to make some different things for each product page in Woocommerce, so I was thinking to use something like:

`is_product('My Product Name')`

But no luck with it. How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is_product - Returns true when viewing a single product. So thats not what you need.

You need to check if the product title is x.

Somethig like:
    $product_title = get_the_title();
    if( $product_title == "your title") // do something

Comment: Anyway i suggest to use post slug and not post name. Like "my-page" and not "My page" to prevent strange characters.

Answer (score 7):

Product titles are subject to change.

Check against an immutable reference instead, like the product ID:

`is_single(31950)`

Verify that you are checking a product page as well:

`is_single(31950) && is_product()`